# Calculate Actual Velocity with Optical Flow

Tags: opencv, opticalflow, drone.io, px4

I have an [Intel Aero quadcopter](https://github.com/intel-aero) with a rangefinder, gyroscope, and downward-facing optical flow calculator. I can get optical flow values in `rad/s`, but I need to estimate the x-and-y velocities of the drone using the information I have available.

I was wondering what the best way to do this is -- how do I relate the angular velocity calculated by the optical flow sensor to the actual velocity of the drone through its environment?

Comment: maybe try asking on physicsSE :)

Comment: @krishna Sorry, why would that help? It's not really physics problem; more of a coding/drone tinkering problem. Thanks!